# Windows accepts a route to a subset of the LAN. Normal?

Tags: windows, windows-7, routing, ip

My laptop's Ethernet NIC has this IP address : 10.0.100.42/16

I noticed that I can add a route to 10.0.115.1/24 (a subset of the laptop subnet) to an external subnet:

> route add 10.0.115.1 mask 255.255.255.0 10.125.3.4

Since this is a subnet of the local LAN, I don't expect this to work. Is it just a bug in Windows 7 or is it an expected behaviour that I can trust to keep working in recent and upcoming Windows versions?

Comment: That seems perfectly normal to me.

Comment: Most systems permit you to have overlapping routes.  Routes are typically processed in the order of most specific to least specific.